# How can I run an android application permanently in the background when the phone is switched on?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am creating an application which is use Service Component and Activity Component ,I want to run the application always in background . Suppose we switch off the mobile and when we on the mobile our application is closed but we want run in that situation also i.e. automatically.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this post answers your question:

http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/starting-android-service-at-boot-time.html

Answer (score 0):

Register for broadcast receiver, look for intent BOOT_COMPLETED. 
Implement the logic to start your application if its not started in its onReceive method. 
Check the following useful links: 
http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/